# MySQL select by password() does not return expected result

Tags: mysql, hash, passwords

In MySQL I execute

```
insert into test (id, pw) values(1, password('1234'));
```

I got

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

I want to search a record by password, so I execute

```
select * from test where pw = password('1234');
```

I expect it to return one row, but I get an empty set. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What sort of output does `PASSWORD()` produce for you?

Comment: Check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/656b85/1, seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL [`Password()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function generates a nonbinary string currently (circa 2016) up to 41 characters. This is visible thru either calls to

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.user;
```

and examining the `password` column (which holds a hashed value):

```
`Password` char(41) ...
```

for, say, MySQL 5.6, or by hashing the same Cleartext value and lining it up to the output of the same `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on MySQL 5.7

```
`authentication_string` text ...
```

The hash values are consistent, yet in a different schema layout. Again, one in a `VARCHAR(41)`, the other in a `TEXT`, as the same [`mysql_native_password`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/native-authentication-plugin.html) PAM is being used. For now. `Password()` became deprecated as of 5.7.6 which means a new Plugin is in the works. Which they should be. They are plugins afterall.

What does it all mean? It means your schema needs to have a wide enough column to handle your use of `Password()` (note 5.7's switch to TEXT). And remember it is deprecated so keep an ear out for changes with MySQL hashing in the next few years.

Comment: the field modify 'varchar(41)' so i did solve problem. very very thank you.